# How to estimate an expected value of $f(x,y)$ when $x$ and $y$ are random

Tags: expected-value

So I have 3 sets of data. I'll call them $x$, $y$, and $z$ (it's not a secret or anything what these variables are, I'm just trying not to distract from the question). $x$ has bounds of 0 to 150 and is random in value; $y$ has bounds of 0 to 7000 and is random in value; and $z$ doesn't have any bounds (typically falls between -.25 to .25 but it can go outside these values), and is a semi-function of $x$ and $y$.

I say $z$ is a semi-function of $x$ and $y$ because this is taken from real world data and there's some variability in the data points. Generally for a given value of $x$ and $y$, all of the $z$ values don't have a lot of variance, but there is some. So my goal is to create a table that expresses an expected value of $z$ for a specific value of $x$ and $y$ using the actual data values (for example, one cell would represent the value of $z$ at $x=50$ and $y=3500$ and display an interpolated value of z given the set of data).

**Question:** What would be this best way to do this?

This isn't a homework problem. I'm trying to write an application to assist in a hobby I have. I have .csv file data logs that is the reference of my question. Then there are input parameters which change the output so I relog, rinse and repeat. This is for a tool to help visualize and adjust the input parameters since I'm looking at a few thousand data points. The goal is to have $z$ be as close to 0 as possible for any value of $x$ and $y$ (although realistically I shoot for -.07 to .07). If you couldn't tell already, $z$ is a correction measurement percentage for a closed loop system. Since $x$ and $y$ are random it can get very tedious to visualize the $z$ value for a given cell.

Answer (score 1):

> ... my goal is to create a table that expresses an expected value of z for a specific value of x and y using the actual data values

What you ask for is the classic regression problem setup: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares.

If you have some prior knowledge on $f(x,y)$ (for simplicity, say, $z = a x + b y$),  you can set up an optimisation problem to find $a$ and $b$ that minimises the squared error (i.e., $\sum_i((a x_i + b y_i) - z_i)^2$).  The resulting solution $(a^*,b^*)$ defines a function $z = a^* x + b^* y$, which is exactly what you seek: $\mathbf{E}[z\;| \;x,y]$.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond, I was trying to do some research. I appreciate the response. I vaguely remember kriging from a geostats class I took a long time ago, is this anything similar to that?

Comment: Yes, kirging is a form of regression.